# Three column layout

Tags: css

beginning from a layout to two column where column-left was fixed and column-right was liquid i have need to add a third column of widht fixed. I have this code:

```
<did id="#container">
  <div id="#col1"> left fixed 15em </div>
  <div id="#col2"> center liquid </div>
  <div id="#col3"> right fixed 15em </div>
</div>
```

With this css:

```
#container {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#col1 {
  float: left;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em; 
  width: 15em;
}
#col2 {
  float: none; 
  width: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em; 
}
#col3 {
  float: right; 
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0.5em; 
  width: 15em;
}
```

The result is that third column it is located below the second column to right. How i can fix this problem?
The final result should to be a layout to three column where left and right column are fixed and central column is liquid.
Thank very much.

Answer (score 2):

I like to use CSS tables for these layouts:

Note that you shouldn't use `#` in the `id` attribute.

```css
#container {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
#container>div {
  display: table-cell;
}
#col1 {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0.5em; 
  width: 15em;
}
#col2 {
  background: lightyellow;
  padding: 0.5em; 
}
#col3 {
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 0.5em; 
  width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="col1"> left fixed 15em </div>
  <div id="col2"> center liquid </div>
  <div id="col3"> right fixed 15em </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/flex) boxes were invented for:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
}
#col2 {
  flex: 1;
}
#col1,
#col3 {
  flex: 0 0 15em;
}
```

```html
<did id="container">
  <div id="col1">left fixed 15em</div>
  <div id="col2">center liquid</div>
  <div id="col3">right fixed 15em</div>
</div>
```

**Extra Info:** This is a very old web layout problem (called the "Holy Grail" of Layouts), see [this article for a complete description](http://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/holy-grail/). Also, see Mozilla's [Using Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes).

**Note:** In `id` properties don't include the `#` (that's used when selecting *by* `id`)

Comment: Flexbox is awesome. With the caveat that old versions of IE don't support it. http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: @JeremyRoman true but caniuse indicates it's under 5% of the browser market. They even work on mobile browsers...

Comment: Indeed. I'm only pointing this out because there are businesses for which their website must also work for that <5%.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your html is invalid :

- `did` should be `div`
- `id="..."` should not contains `#`

HTML updated:

```
<div id="container">
   <div id="col1"> left fixed 15em </div>
   <div id="col2"> center liquid </div>
   <div id="col3"> right fixed 15em </div>
</div>
```

For the CSS, you can change your rule `#col2` `float: none` to `float: left`

JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/ghorg12110/5p175fms/

Comment: Hello, trying to change as you told i have all it below and second column below the first taking all space.

Comment: @MarcelloImpastato this is because of the container width: if the 3 columns can't be placed on the first line (because the 3 width are > to the container one) one bloc will go below.

Comment: thank, but central column is liquid so it should result in same row.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Three column layout</title>
<style>
body { margin: 0; overflow: hidden }
#V { position: absolute; top: 1em; left: 1em; width: 15em; border: 1px solid red; padding: .5em }
#W { position: absolute; top: 1em; right: 1em; bottom: 0; left: 1em; margin: 0 17em }
#X { border: 1px solid blue; padding: .5em }
#Y { position: absolute; top: 1em; right: 1em; width: 15em; border: 1px solid green; padding: .5em }
</style>
<div id=V>
Left content
</div>
<div id=W>
<div id=X>
Middle content
</div>
</div>
<div id=Y>
Right content
</div>
```